# ListView covers everything below it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am implementing a class where I list languages for a country in a ListView. Right below that I have a ExpandableListView that has Major Languages In the Group Title and all the versions of that language as its children.

Currently the data is populated correctly but the list view is displayed over a divider and the ExpandableListView. I want the user to be able to scroll through all of the items in both lists without having both lists height statically defined. Currently when the ListView  has more items in it then display on one screen it only displays the list view and things above it and covers up the ExpandableListView.

**language_list.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="type to filter list" 
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
    android:maxLines="1"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/languages" 
    android:text="Locatoin Languages" 
    android:background="#fff"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@id/search_box"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
</TextView>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/expandableLanguage" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/languages"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/majorLanguages" 
    android:text="Major Languages" 
    android:background="#fff"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@id/expandableLanguage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
</TextView>

<ExpandableListView 
    android:id="@+id/expandableMajorLanguage" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/majorLanguages">
</ExpandableListView>

<requestFocus></requestFocus>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**LanguageList.Java**

```
public class LanguageList extends Activity {
private static LocalSQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private static String BASE_LANGUAGE_SELECTOR = "";
private static String GET_MAJOR_LANGUAGES_BY_MACRO = "";
private static String GET_MAJOR_LANGUAGES_BY_ISO = "";
private static String GET_MAJOR_LANGUAGES_TITLES = "";

ExpandableListAdapter adapterExpandable;
ListAdapter adapterList;

String locationName, locationID, languageName;
private ArrayList<LanguageDataType> LocationLanguages = new ArrayList<LanguageDataType>();
private ArrayList<LanguageDataType> majorLanguagesTitles = new ArrayList<LanguageDataType>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<LanguageDataType>> majorLanguages = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LanguageDataType>>();
private ExpandableListView languageLV ; 
private ListView locationLV;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.language_list);
    setTitle("Select Languages");
    dbHelper = new LocalSQLiteHelper(this.getBaseContext());
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Bundle locationData = getIntent().getExtras();

    locationName = locationData.getString("locationName");
    locationID = locationData.getString("locationID");


    getLocationData();
    getMajorLanguageData();




    languageLV=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableMajorLanguage);
    languageLV.getAdapter();
    adapterExpandable=new LanguageExpandableAdapter(this, majorLanguagesTitles, majorLanguages);
    languageLV.setAdapter(adapterExpandable);


    locationLV= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableLanguage);
    locationLV.getAdapter();
    adapterList=new LanguageListAdapter(this, LocationLanguages);
    locationLV.setAdapter( adapterList);

}

private void getLocationData(){
    //locationTitle.clear();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.languages);
    text.setText("Languages spoken in " +locationName);

    LocationLanguages.clear();
    //locationTitle.add(new LanguageDataType("Languages spoken in " +locationName, null, null));
    Cursor row = null;
    row = db.rawQuery(BASE_LANGUAGE_SELECTOR + locationID + "';", null);

    if((row.getCount() > 0) && (!row.isClosed())){
        row.moveToFirst();
        do{ 
            LocationLanguages.add(new LanguageDataType(row.getString(0), row.getString(1),row.getString(2)));
        }while(row.moveToNext());
        row.close();            
    } 
}



private void getMajorLanguageData(){
    majorLanguagesTitles.clear();
    majorLanguages.clear();

    Cursor row = null;
    row = db.rawQuery(GET_MAJOR_LANGUAGES_TITLES, null);

    if((row.getCount() > 0) && (!row.isClosed())){
        row.moveToFirst();
        do{ 
            majorLanguagesTitles.add(new LanguageDataType(row.getString(0), row.getString(1),row.getString(2)));

            if(row.getString(2)==null){
                queryLanguages(GET_MAJOR_LANGUAGES_BY_ISO + row.getString(1) + "';", majorLanguages);
            } else {
                queryLanguages(GET_MAJOR_LANGUAGES_BY_MACRO + row.getString(2) + "';", majorLanguages);
            }           
        }while(row.moveToNext());
        row.close();            
    } 
}

private void queryLanguages(String sql,ArrayList<ArrayList<LanguageDataType>> inputList ) {     

    Cursor row = null;
    row = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    ArrayList<LanguageDataType> languageList = new ArrayList<LanguageDataType>();

    if((row.getCount() > 0) && (!row.isClosed())){
        row.moveToFirst();
        do{ 
            languageList.add(new LanguageDataType(row.getString(0), row.getString(1),row.getString(2)));
        }while(row.moveToNext());
        row.close();            
    } 
    inputList.add(languageList);
}
```

---

I have two adapters one for the `ListView` and other for the `ExpandableListView`.

**LanguageExpandableAdapter.java**

```
public class LanguageExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
Context mContext;
private ArrayList<LanguageDataType> titles = new ArrayList<LanguageDataType>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<LanguageDataType>> languages = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LanguageDataType>>();


public LanguageExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LanguageDataType> inputTitles, ArrayList<ArrayList<LanguageDataType>> inputLanguages) {
    mContext = context;

    for (LanguageDataType value: inputTitles) {
        titles.add(value);
    }

    for (ArrayList<LanguageDataType> value: inputLanguages) {
        languages.add(value);
    }

}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return languages.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getLocationName();
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return languages.get(groupPosition).size();
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView childeTitle = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = null;
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_language_child_row, null);
    childeTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_element);
    String myText = this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString();
    childeTitle.setText(myText);

    return v;

}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return titles.get(groupPosition).getLocationName();
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return titles.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView groupTitle = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = null;
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_language_group_row, null);
    groupTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_element);
    String myText = this.getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
    groupTitle.setText(myText);

    return v;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```

---

LanguageListAdapter.java

```
public class LanguageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
List<LanguageDataType> language = new ArrayList<LanguageDataType>();
List<LanguageDataType> origLocation = new ArrayList<LanguageDataType>();

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;



public LanguageListAdapter(Activity listActivity, List<LanguageDataType> LanguageList) {
    activity = listActivity;

    for (LanguageDataType value: LanguageList) {
        language.add(value);
    }

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public int getCount() {
    return language.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_language_child_row, null);
    }

    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text_element);
    text.setText(language.get(position).getLocationName());

    return vi;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}
```

---

If anyone has any suggestions how I can have a continual scroll through `ListView` and onto my `extendableListView` I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the ExpandableListView first, aligned at the bottom of the screen and then define the Listview as being above the ExpandableListView.

Comment: When I try that the ExpandableListView shows up but the ListView will no longer show. I made sure that the data was still being populated correctly and it is.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to do it is to split the screen between the two...  I don't know of any way to scroll two scrollable items.

If you had two regular listviews I could point you to a solution, but a listview and an expandable listview won't work with that solution.

The best I can come up with is to change the two listview definitions in the xml to contain:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

That would cause them to splict the screen between them and keep them both on the screen.